# How do I convert a filter from Spatial to Fourier domain?

Tags: image-processing, fft, filter-design, resampling

I have a small 2D Gaussian image filter that I am currently applying as a window by convolution. I would like to do this in the Fourier domain as a single multiplication. I would like to convert my current small filter to the Fourier domain as it is with maximum possible fidelity.

I do not know the size of the image that I shall be applying it on and want to be able to dynamically change it for any image size. How do I go about doing this?

Can I scale my filter to the image size (**square to rectangle**), FFT the scaled and now distorted and multiply in the Fourier domain?

or

Should I FFT it first, scale up (**square to rectangle**) and distort the FFT and then multiply it?

I am not convinced that either is a correct approach. Are there any alternative ways?

I am working with this in MATLAB

Comment: Do you know the spatial expression for the filter? Gaussian filters have an analytic form in the Fourier domain as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a low-pass filter that is small compared to the image you can put your filter (unscaled) in the center of a square/rectangle the size and shape of your image (all the other pixels are 0), take the FFT and multiply the result  in the Fourier domain.

Since you are using a Gaussian filter you *could* do something more efficient than that.  The Gaussian filter is _ separable_ so you can actually create a 2D Gaussian filter by doing a 1D Gaussian filter in every row (column) in one dimension followed by a 1D Gaussian filter in every column (row) in the other dimension.

Second, the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian.  So we can work in one dimension at a time, we know what we're going to get, and multiplying a Gaussian in the Fourier domain is also separable since $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}=e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}$.  The only question is what the standard deviation ($\sigma$) of the transformed Gaussian is going to be.  The derivation is worked out on [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html) as:
$$
\mathcal{F}[e^{-ax^2}](k)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-\pi^2k^2/a}.
$$

Comment: The only trouble with doing this is that the image resulting may have circular (spatial) aliasing. If the image is $N\times N$ and the filter is $N \times N$ then the resulting (convolved) image needs to be $2N -1 \times 2N - 1$ to avoid such aliasing.

Comment: You are correct.  I modified the opening paragraph.  I think that the technique works for small low-pass filters.  I hadn't thought about the more general case.